# Union function works over a range but the Range function won't

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to select a continuous range inside of a table determined by variable references using VBA. I have run into an issue where I can use the Union function to select 2 points, but cannot use the Range function in order to create a continuous range.

For context, here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
For i = 1 to 5

     Set colrng = Table2.HeaderRowRange
     Set rowrng = Range(Range("B3"), Range("B" & CStr(2 + Table2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)))

     col = WorksheetFunction.Match(Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 1), colrng, 0)
     row = WorksheetFunction.Match(Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 4), rowrng, 0)

     Union(Table2.DataBodyRange(row, col), Table2.DataBodyRange(row + 2, col)) = "New Value"

Next
```

The code as of right now works, but results in 2 disjointed cells containing "New Value", whereas I would prefer if every cell between and inclusive of the two endpoints contained "New Value". The method I have used in the past on less advanced code utilizes the Range function, but that doesn't work here and yields an error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object defined error

Edit: I don't think I was clear enough in my initial example, so below is the full code I am using.

```
Private Sub test()
    
    Dim colrng As Range
    Dim rowrng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim t As Double
    Dim Schedule As ListObject
    Dim Info As ListObject
    
    Set Schedule = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set Info = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table2")
    
    Schedule.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    
    
    For i = 1 To Info.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        
        t = Info.DataBodyRange(i, 5) - 1
        
        Set colrng = Schedule.HeaderRowRange
        Set rowrng = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("B3"), Sheet1.Range("B" & CStr(2 + Schedule.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)))
        
        If IsEmpty(Info.DataBodyRange(i, 4)) = False And IsEmpty(Info.DataBodyRange(i, 1)) = False Then
        
            c = Application.Match(Info.DataBodyRange(i, 1), colrng, 0)
            r = Application.Match(Info.DataBodyRange(i, 4), rowrng, 0)
            
            Range(Schedule.DataBodyRange(r, c), Schedule.DataBodyRange(r + t, c)) = Info.DataBodyRange(i, 2) & " - " & Info.DataBodyRange(i, 3)
            
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Where info is this table:

[image]

And the Schedule table with the desired output is:

[image]

As of right now, using the *Union* function in place of the *Range* function in the last row before the closing code I am able to generate all of the desired output aside from the cell D8 being empty.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I am using the variable names *c* and *r* on my end but when I posted it here I meant to change them all over to *col* and *row* for clarity. Edit: The issue has been amended, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: so the issue was just a typo and this is otherwise solved?

Comment: @BruceWayne no.

Comment: @RichardJ what are the addresses of those cells, and what are the values of `row` and `col` when this fails? I can't repro. I would use `Application.Match` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match` though, and then test if the result is an error before trying to use `col` and `row`.

Comment: Are you saying that you tried `Range(Cells(r,c),Cells(r+2,c)).value = "New Value"` and that did not work?  I'm not seeing what `Range()` functino you tried, which might be a syntactical issue.

Comment: Additionally, you have `Match()` functions that do not reference `.Row`, which would make the above listed line more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.

@Ben: I changed to Application.Match and the same error still occurs. The mismatched variable names were purely on the StackOverflow code, which I had intended to edit but neglected to change them all.

Cyril: For the range function, that is correct, the range function I attempted was Range(Table2.DataBodyRange(row, col), Table2.DataBodyRange(row + 2, col)) = "New Value" (replacing 'Union' with 'Range' in the code I've posted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comment, I believe your issue has to do with how to define a range and the below changes may support using `Range()` rather than union:

```
For i = 1 to 5
     Set colrng = Table2.HeaderRowRange
     Set rowrng = Range(Range("B3"), Range("B" & CStr(2 + Table2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)))
     'EDIT:  You start with cell B3, so adding col+1 and row+2
     col = Application.Match(Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 1), colrng, 0) + 1 'CHANGE
     row = Application.Match(Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 4), rowrng, 0) + 2 'CHANGE
     'range().value = "new value" and will utilize cells()
     Range(Cells(row, col+1), Cells(row + 2, col+1)).Value = "New Value" 'CHANGE
Next
```

Please remember to fully-qualify your references.  In `rowrng` you just have `range()` references, but what sheet is that on?  some of that info may have an impact depending on the layout and usage of your workbook.

Additionally, changed `WorksheetFunction` to `Application` which allows for different error handling.  This may or may not be benefitial to you.

Comment: @ScottCraner Was working on explaining the +1 and +2 based on starting with B3 when I saw your second comment come in... if nothing else, it helps to have confirmation!